# how to force div at the bottom of page when dynamically inserting data

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a page with some divs. My page is pretty dynamic where I am showing and hiding divs based on user input.

I want a footer to always appear at the bottom and to have the other divs above it appear in a scroll. Since my data is populated asynchronously, my view loads but then once the content is injected onto the page, my footer seems to move

Here's a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="dynamic-div1">async div1</div>
    <div class="dynamic-div2">async div2</div>
    <div class="footer">Always appear at bottom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "at bottom" meaning fixed to the bottom of the viewport?

Comment: how about if you create a wrapper div for your dynamic contents?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/ heres 5 ways to create a fixed footer

Answer (score 0):

try to add positions for footer

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="dynamic-div1">async div1</div>
    <div class="dynamic-div2">async div2</div>
    <div class="footer">Always appear at bottom</div>
</div>
```

in CSS

```
.footer
{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in HTML

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="dynamic-div1">async div1</div>
   <div class="dynamic-div2">async div2</div>
   <div class="footer">Always appear at bottom</div>
</div>
```

in CSS

```
div.parent{
position:relative;
}
div.footer
{
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for the fixed footer at bottom. You can use `position:fixed` and apply positions like below.

```css
.footer {
  position:fixed;
  height:20px;
  background:#ccc;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="dynamic-div1">async div1</div>
    <div class="dynamic-div2">async div2</div>
    <div class="footer">Always appear at bottom</div>
</div>
```